# Excel highlighting selected cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, highlighting

I'm currently working in Excel a lot (MS Excel 2016) and searching for values.
In the search result if I'm clicking on an entry, in the background automatically the cell is selected.

Unfortunately the highlighting is to weak for me - that means that I have to look around to find the selected cell a lot.

Is there a general  way to make the highlighting stronger?
So that:

- the column/row title is selected in a different color (currently in a slightly darker gray)
- the selected cell boarder have a more highlighting color (currently green) like a red

Is there a general way to do this without macros that would have to be put in every file?

Comment: One simple & handy method I can suggest you to change the color of Grid line (Cell border). In `File Menu`, hit the `Option` then `Advanced` find `Display Option for this worksheet`, there you may select the Sheet, Find `Gridline Color` and change any bright one like Blue. Return to the Sheet now you find grid lines are more prompt & bright. **If you wanna to HIGHLIGHT the selected cell the MACRO is the option.**

Comment: Other is, create blank Workbook, apply all kind of possible formating , including Grid line, Font & Fill color  and use Save as to save it as TEMPLATE in this folder`C:Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office14/XLSTART.` Then every blank workbook should contain the formatting you previously set.

Comment: But these are not general solutions. I have to apply them all the time gain as the files are not generated with he macros and macros as simply bad.